# Solution check: $e^{\cos x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}$, determine $a_n$ for $n\leq 5$, does this solution make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

On my caculus book, there is a question: Suppose the Taylor expansion of $e^{\cos x}$ is $e^{\cos x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}$, determine the value of $a_n$ for $n\leq5$. Here is the solution the book offered, but I don’t think it makes much sense.

> $e^{\cos x}=ee^{\cos x-1}=e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{(\cos x-1)}^n}{n!}=e\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(-1\right)^m\frac{x^{2m}}{(2m)!}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\right)$,
> and $x^2$ only appears when $n=1$, $x^4$ only appears when $n=2$ or
> $n=4$, so $a_0=e$, $a_1=a_3=0$, $a_2=-\frac{e}{2}$, $a_4=\frac{e}{6}$.

But I think this solution doesn’t make sense in two aspects. First, in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(-1\right)^m\frac{x^{2m}}{(2m)!}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}\right)$, both $m$ and $n$ goes to infty, how to interpret the value of this using the $\epsilon-N$ definition? Next, I think the writer used this argument:

> Since
> $e^{\cos x-1}-1-(\cos x-1)-\frac{(\cos x-1)^2}{2}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\cos x-1\right)^n}{n!}$,
> and for $n\geq3$ the Taylor expansion of
> $\frac{\left(\cos x-1\right)^n}{n!}$ doesn’t contain $x^4$, then the
> Taylor expansion of $ e^{\cos x-1}-1-(\cos x-1)-\frac{(\cos x-1)^2}{2}$
> doesn’t contain $x^4$ either.

But does this make sense? Since $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\cos x-1\right)^n}{n!}$ actually means $\sum_{n=3}^{k}\frac{\left(\cos x-1\right)^n}{n!}+r(k; x)$
and for fixed $x$, $r(k;x)\rightarrow(n\rightarrow \infty)$, I don’t think the inference is rational.

Comment: The double sum doesn't look correct. The correct sum will be $$ e^{\cos x}=e \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^m\frac{x^{2m}}{(2m)!}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee That's not correct either

Comment: @jjagmath, You are right, I forgot to write the factorial symbol there. Now it is fixed :)

Comment: You say three times that you don't think it makes sense. You should instead be asking us: _why_ does this make sense? After all, the author of the book knows more about infinite series than you do. (Also, you have two typos in your double sum, as @SangchulLee points out $-$ are these yours, or the book's?)

Comment: Well, this is my typo. I will fix it. And next time I shall pay attention to the way of asking a question.

Comment: You fogot the extra $e$ factor after the second equality. Also when you write down the double sum again, it is better to start with $n=0$ rather than $n=1$ just to be consistent.

Comment: @Gary Yes, this is also a typo. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way that may be able to explain it. Given the Taylor expansion and the Taylor formula with Peano remainder has the same coefficient, and $e^{cosx}$ is real-analytic since $e^x$ and $cosx$ are real-analytic, we can determine the coefficient of the Taylor formula with Peano remainder with the rule that $o(a(x))o(b(x))=o(a(x)b(x))$, and hence the coefficient of the Taylor expansion.